# Error in python numexp module with 'and' operator

Tags: python, numexpr

I'm using the [numexpr](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module for python.
I'm trying to run the next code snippet:

```
import numexpr as ne


def main():
    result = ne.evaluate('where((1 > 9) & (where(1 > 9, 9, 1) == 0), 2, 3)')
    print(f'Result: {result}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But `numexpr` throws the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'ConstantNode'
```

However, if I extract the conflicting section in a separate expression, it works.

```
def main():
    intermediate_result = ne.evaluate('where(1 > 9, 9, 1) == 0')
    result = ne.evaluate(f'where((1 > 9) & {intermediate_result}, 2, 3)')
    print(f'Result: {result}')
```

But the idea is to have a single expression.
Does anyone know how I could rewrite this formula to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the & to be a logical AND? I am assuming you do, in which case you probably just need a double ampersand (&&), otherwise you're doing to do a bitwise AND, which is an arithmetic operation and "True" isn't a number in python.

Comment: @TomLubenow: what does it mean ""True" isn't a number in python"? `True` is a `bool` which is a subclass of `int`, `int` is a numeric type -> `True` is a number

Comment: @TomLubenow `True` is a keyword that means `1`

Comment: You guys appear to be right (you learn something new every day) but I would still consider it a bad idea to do arithmetic on booleans.

Comment: Thanks @TomLubenow, the `and` operator worked. Sorry but the documentation never mention that operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is the bitwise `and` operator. Why not just use `and`?

Comment: Thanks @alec_a, the `and` operator worked. Sorry but the documentation never mention that operator.

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped, would you mind accepting it? It grants you a small rep boost.